# Get only the users that contain a certain list column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1','2','3'],'List_Origin':[['A','B'],['B','C'],['A','B']]})
```

How could i only get the ids, that contain only a certain List_Origin, for example 'A','B'. Would appreciate if the solution avoided loops

Wanted end result

```
end_df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1','3'],'List_Origin':[['A','B'],['A','B']]})
```

Comment: is it expected to have a mix of lists and strings? what is a "*solution method based*"?

Comment: I rephrased it so it could be better understood

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Is the length of the lists same in all rows ?

Comment: Well in the real dataframe they vary a lot but i guess it is okay for now  the given solutiosn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and check like below:

```
>>> df[df['List_Origin'].apply(lambda x: x==['A', 'B'] or x==['A,B'])]

   Id   List_Origin
0   1   [A,B]
2   3   [A, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when using lists, you cannot vectorize. You must use a loop.

I am assuming first that you have `['A', 'B']` and not `['A,B']` in the first row:

```
end_df = df[[x==['A', 'B'] for x in df['List_Origin']]]
```

output:

```
  Id List_Origin
0  1      [A, B]
2  3      [A, B]
```

If, really, you have a mix of `['A', 'B']` and `['A,B']`, then use:

```
end_df = df[[','.join(x)=='A,B' for x in df['List_Origin']]]
```

output:

```
  Id List_Origin
0  1       [A,B]
2  3      [A, B]
```

Comment: Was a typo sorry about that no need for the mixed part.

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 OK, well it's here anyway, might be useful to someone else ;)